# Add a reference in Visual Studio 2017, no button for "Add references"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I am trying to add AForge.Math.dll to my C# project with Visual Studio 2017, but I am unable to do so. I've seen countless guides on how to do it, going from Solution view > References > Right click > Add reference, but I can't do that.

[image]

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure you've got a C# project there?

Comment: because it is obscured, can you confirm specifically what sort of project your camera simulator is

Comment: It's a Unity3d project, can be hard to see, but the icon left to "Camera simulator" has a  distinctive green "C#"

Comment: Unity3D projects are their own thing, even though they contain C# code. Apparently they [don't support references, having gone with some sort of plugin system instead](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1166095/visual-studio-adding-custom-references.html).

Comment: Well, that was hard to know. I just started a Unity project on my own after working with one with some friends and I had no idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Right click on Project name i.e. Camera Simulator and then you will option to add reference.

Answer (score 2):

You should create **Plugins** folder inside **Assets** folder and put your dll into **Plugins** folder. Unity should add reference to your library automatically, if there are no problems with dll. After that you can use your library in your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a folder in Unity Assets and call it Plugins or any name, then drag and drop the MySQL.data file in order to start working properly in your Scripts in Visual Studio, and connect the database to unity